# Add extra characters in addtocarturl

Tags: magento2, php, cart, phtml

I am using this below code to add a product to the cart from a phtml file:

```
<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post"> 
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
    <div class="btn">
        <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary">
            <span>Add to Cart</span>
        </button>
    </div>   
 </form>
```

But at $addToCartUrl, I receive some extra characters like this:

> www.webi.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGliby50di8yMDE4OS9ibGk%2C/product/2/

The part before **/product/2/** adds these characters: `%2C` and in this way, I can't add the product to cart!

Comment: which place you have keep query string product/2?

Comment: that part its ok, but if you look it, before that part, you have the %2C that is added, and that cause my product to not add it to cart.
I don't understand why its that part added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also having this same issue before while tried to add to cart from phtml. So, I try this way which is works fine for me. Try this -

Step 1: (Mention this function under any helper and use scope interface)

```
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

public function getAddToCartUrl(){ 
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('checkout/cart/add');
    }
```

Step 2: (Call this function in your phtml as a from action)

```
    $_Helper = $this->helper('Custom\Wholesalecart\Helper\Data');

    <form action="<?php echo $_Helper->getAddToCartUrl() ?>" method="post">
       <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
       {{Your content here}}
        <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary">
           <span>Add to Cart</span>
        </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I can try this, but where should I put product ID to add to cart?

Comment: Put this `<input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />` and qty box like `<input name="qty" id="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" data-validate="null" type="number">` where i have mentioned "{{Your content here}}"

Answer (score 0):

**Use html_entity_decode()** to remove unnecessary character encode.

```
<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo html_entity_decode($addToCartUrl); ?>" method="post"> 
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
    <div class="btn">
        <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary">
            <span>Add to Cart</span>
        </button>
    </div>   
 </form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still the same issue.